# Elasticsearch river, convert longitude latitude to geo_point

Tags: mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch

I'm using the MySQL JPrante JDBC River plugin for Elasticsearch to index data from MySQL.

In a recordset I have the fields longitude (`float`), latitude (`float`), pin (`POINT`), how I can preset them to be detected as a `geo_point` in elasticsearch?

I have tried with :

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/mysql_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "strategy": "simple",
    "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedatabase",
    "user": "someuser",
    "password": "somepassword",
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM activities",
    "poll": "30m",
    "rounding": null,
    "scale": 0,
    "autocommit": false,
    "fetchsize": 10,
    "max_rows": 0,
    "max_retries": 3,
    "max_retries_wait": "10s",
    "digesting": true,
    "acksql": null,
    "acksqlparams": null
  },
  "index": {
    "index": "jdbc",
    "type": "jdbc",
    "bulk_size": 100,
    "max_bulk_requests": 30,
    "index_settings": null,
    "type_mapping": {
      "location_mapping": {
        "properties": {
          "pin": {
            "type": "geo_point",
            "lat_lon": true,
            "store": "yes"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "versioning": false,
    "acknowledge": false
  }
}'
```

[UPDATE 1]

here is the error with mapping name change to jdbc as described by javanna:

```
[2013-05-21 13:20:58,256][WARN ][river.jdbc               ] [node-0] [jdbc][mysql_jdbc_river] failed to create index [jdbc], disabling JDBC river...
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Failed to parse mapping definition
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.extractMapping(DocumentMapperParser.java:245)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:155)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:383)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:379)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$4.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:310)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$2.run(InternalClusterService.java:229)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
 at [Source: {jdbc={properties={pin={lat_lon=true, type=geo_point}}}}; line: 1, column: 7]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1378)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:599)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:520)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:616)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.nextToken(JsonXContentParser.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.XContentMapConverter.readMap(XContentMapConverter.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.XContentMapConverter.readOrderedMap(XContentMapConverter.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.mapOrdered(AbstractXContentParser.java:126)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.extractMapping(DocumentMapperParser.java:243)
    ... 9 more
[2013-05-21 13:20:58,264][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [node-0] [_river] update_mapping [mysql_jdbc_river] (dynamic)
```

Comment: You have tried and? Any error? What do you get back when you retrieve the mapping using the get mapping api? Does it get applied?

Comment: First of all the type name in your mapping does not match the type you configured when registering the river. Should be `jdbc`.

Comment: Looks like a problem in your json but I can't see it at first glance. Just validate it before sending it.

Comment: I validated the json on several online json validator.  But just to be sure i past the one above and it's valid on http://jsonlint.com/...

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the type_mapping JSON as a string.